# How to use 'fill' twice in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-bar

I am trying to make a bar chart in which I separate a variable using two other variables using `fill` in `ggplot2`. However, it does not allow me to use `fill` twice so at the moment I have used `alpha` but it does not look good.

Is there a way I can use fill twice? Or another aesthetic parameter I can use instead of `alpha` to get a better-looking graph.

My code is:

```r
ggplot(data = s1, aes(x = Income, y = count2,
                      fill = Mental_Health_Prob,
                      alpha = Smoked_Regularly)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

And it gives me this graph:
[image: graph]

Comment: You may create facets over `smoked_regularly`? wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: Pleae provide a reproducible example! :  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new variable that contains the possible combinations of your two binary variables (easy with `forcats::fct_cross()`) and then pass that to the `fill` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Create minimal reproducible example data
s1 <- data.frame(Income = c("low", "middle", "high"),
                 Mental_Health_Prob = rep(c("Yes", "No"), each = 6),
                 Smoked_Regularly = rep(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), each = 3),
                 count2 = c(350, 220, 100, 345, 123, 564, 315, 374, 174, 534, 362, 432))

# Plot
s1 |>
    mutate(MH_smok = fct_cross(Mental_Health_Prob, Smoked_Regularly, sep = "_")) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = Income, y = count2, fill = MH_smok)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You will want to give the variable and its levels more meaningful descriptions.